# Structure - Unknown Size

Tags: c, structure, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm currently trying to allocate a structure of unknown size.  I know the below works, but my question is how can I perform the below, if I don't know the size of "num" in advance?  When I try to allocate `*num` directly with `malloc` and a size of 2, it doesn't let me access `num[0]` and `num[1]`, like I've been able to do with the int array pointers.

I know I can do the above if I'm not using a structure.  For example, `int *A` with `malloc(10*(sizeof(int *))`, lets me access `a[0]`, along with `a[5]`.  With structures, it doesn't seem like I'm able to do this, but I'm probably just doing something wrong.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct
{
char word[50];
} test;

int main(void)
{
    test *num[2];
    num[0]=(test *)malloc(3*sizeof(test *));
    num[1]=(test *)malloc(3*sizeof(test *));
    strcpy(num[0]->word, "hello");
    strcpy(num[1]->word, "... you");
    puts(num[0]->word);
    puts(num[1]->word);
}
```

Comment: Look into what vectors and linked lists are...

Comment: Also, where does `3*sizeof (test*))` come from? That seems bogus.

Comment: `num[0]=(test *)malloc(3*sizeof(test *));` is amiss.  Use `num[0]=malloc(sizeof num[0][0]);`.

Comment: I just copied the code, from before, when I was trying to allocate *num=malloc... I thought increasing the size of *num by 3 would let me access 3 elements within num somehow (logically 3 elements*sizeof(each element), but alas, that doesn't seem to be the case.  I also failed to free the data, which is a bad habit.

Comment: "I'm currently trying to allocate a structure of unknown size" No you aren't. The size of the structure is well-known, it is `sizeof(test)` which is 50 bytes (+ potential padding). It is definitely not `sizeof(test *)` which is the size of a pointer, and it is just allocating a pointer-sized chunk which won't make anyone happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally:

`sizeof (test *)` (the size of a pointer) is not guaranteed to be the same as (i.e., here, surely less than) `sizeof (test)` (what that pointer *points to*; here, the size of a structure).

On my machine

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    char word[50];
} test;

int main(void)
{
    printf("sizeof (test) = %zu\n", sizeof (test));
    printf("sizeof (test *) = %zu\n", sizeof (test *));
}
```

produces

```
sizeof (test) = 50
sizeof (test *) = 8
```

A *short* allocation means there will not be enough memory to represent the structure members, and undefined behaviour when you exhaust said memory. You appear to have experienced problems, and attempted to remedy them by tripling the size of each allocation, as shown in the example. This is still an incorrect amount of memory if you want pointers to three contiguous structures, but enough memory that copying a small string (e.g., `strlen(str) < 3 * sizeof (test *)`) to just the first of these structures is unlikely to cause issues (i.e., segfault).

In your test with `int`s, the same mistake is unlikely to raise any eyebrows. Again, on my machine

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("sizeof (int) = %zu\n", sizeof (int));
    printf("sizeof (int *) = %zu\n", sizeof (int *));
}
```

produces

```
sizeof (int) = 4
sizeof (int *) = 8
```

Using `sizeof (int *)` bytes to store an `int` object is likely an over-allocation of memory at worst, maybe break-even. You can check your machine if you are curious, but it does not particularly matter - if you use `sizeof` on the correct expression, you will have the correct amount of memory.

The general form is

```
T *foo = malloc(sizeof *foo); // equivalent: sizeof (T)
```

where you are allocating the number of bytes required to store the object itself (not the pointer to said object). This does not change if the pointer value will be assigned to an element in an array.

```
T *bar[3];
bar[0] = malloc(sizeof *bar[0]); // equivalent: sizeof (T)
```

---

For the more specific question, which can be rephrased as

> How do I allocate an array which might need to change sizes?

the answer is start with an optimistic or otherwise default length, and allocate enough memory with `malloc` (or `calloc`; or start with a `NULL` pointer value in the event that your starting length is zero). When space requirements change, resize the array with `realloc`.

Here is an arbitrary example that *grows* an array, one element at a time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct line {
    char buf[64];
};

int main(void)
{
    size_t length = 0;
    struct line *lines = NULL;

    struct line current;

    while (1) {
        printf("> ");

        if (!fgets(current.buf, sizeof current.buf, stdin))
            break;

        void *mem = realloc(lines, sizeof *lines * (length + 1));

        if (!mem) {
            fputs("Out of memory.\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }

        lines = mem;
        lines[length++] = current;
    }

    putchar('\n');

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
        fputs(lines[i].buf, stdout);

    free(lines);
}
```

```
> hello
> world
> 
hello
world
```

Comment: Interesting, it's almost treated as a standard structure array with the "." Operator.  Always thought it used the -> operator.  Thank you for the example!

Answer (score 2):

`3*sizeof(test *)`, i.e. 3 times the size of a pointer is nonsense.  Prefer using variables instead of types of `sizeof`.  This allows you to use a general pattern `type *foo = malloc(sizeof *foo);` and leads to less repetition.  You can use an array of pointers, of course, which means you need to allocate the array and each element, or just allocate an array of elements like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char word[50];
} test;

test *create_test(size_t n) {
    test *t = malloc(sizeof *t * n);
    return t;
}

int main(void) {
    test *num = create_test(42);
    if(!num) {
        fprintf(stderr, "create_test failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    strcpy(num[0].word, "hello");
    strcpy(num[41].word, "... you");
    puts(num[0].word);
    puts(num[41].word);
}
```

[Don't cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/should-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/) the `void *` from `malloc()`.